# Why don't solar cells produce visible light when supplied with electricity?

Tags: solar-cell, light, reverse-polarity

... A cursory Google search didn't reveal an answer...  Is the energy conversion a one-way process?

Comment: This is interesting: http://news.discovery.com/tech/alternative-power-sources/solar-panel-by-day-light-panel-at-night-140324.htm

Comment: Which frequency of light were you expecting to get?

Comment: @samuel the same frequencies that are input to the cell to generate electricity. ??

Comment: Your use of question marks is confusing. Are you now asking me if that is what you were expecting? My question was a hint to you that the visible spectrum is an incredibly narrow band of the light frequencies hitting a solar panel, thus it's far more likely you simply can not see the light they emit when the process is reversed. How do you know they don't produce light?

Comment: I was confused by your question. I should have clearly stated 'visible light' in my question, but just assumed that was obvious. Edited my question. So you're saying solar cells radiate IR/UV when powered? If so, would the efficiency of conversion from electrical energy to light be approximately the same as light to electricity?

Comment: All diodes radiate *some* frequency of photon. The specific frequencies depend on the diode's bandgap.

Comment: So to summarize, is answer that 'they do produce visible light, just very inefficiently'?

Comment: They do produce light, not all of it visible.

Comment: LOL... In combustion ... if u turn your engine did u get petrol ????

Comment: @obrut LOL and heating a reactor core produces uranium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that they don't, its just very inefficient in reverse bias. Non-visible and very weak, Heat buildup, fragile silicon crystal structure. Typical Solar PV cells are made using silicon crystals just like IC silicon wafers. It's the same reason that LEDs arn't made with silicon.

["Digikey: Will Silicon Substrates Push LED Lighting Into the Mainstream?"](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2013/sep/will-silicon-substrates-push-led-lighting-into-the-mainstream)

> The reason why LEDs are expensive is partly because the manufacturing process used to fabricate the wafers from which the individual chips are cut is difficult and employs exotic materials such as gallium nitride (GaN) deposited on sapphire or silicon-carbide (SiC) substrates.
>
> But recently, some manufacturers have proposed using silicon, the material routinely used to fabricate billions of integrated circuits (ICs) every year, as an LED substrate. Apart from potentially reducing the cost of LEDs, the use of mature complementary metal oxide semiconductor (CMOS) IC technology would allow fabrication in conventional wafer fabs that have spare capacity.
>
> However, the idea is not new. Silicon has been tried before, **but large mismatches between its crystal structure and coefficient of thermal expansion, and those of the GaN used for the LED proper created faults that lowered the end product’s efficacy and dramatically shortened its life.** Now new developments promise to overcome these drawbacks.

Comment: I also understand that LEDs can convert light to electrical energy and thus can be used as light detectors as well as emitters.

Comment: @RyanGriggs: Yes, that is true. The GaN used in LEDs is actually pretty efficient as a 'solar cell', but here another problem throws a wrench in the symmetry: there is a phosphorus re-emission layer on top of most (white) LEDs. You need to get a 'royal blue' (i.e. uncoated) LED to be able to effectively use it as a solar cell. Then again, these aren't cost optimized at all, so it's an academic exercise anyway.

Comment: @user36129 they meant more as in using an led as a photodiode or ldr type sensor than as an energy source, but you are correct.

Answer (score -3):

Yea, Si is not optimal for emission, but absorption. LED's are made with semiconductors that are optimal for emission such as Indium Gallium Arsenide.

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer. What is it that makes a particular semiconductor material "optimal" for either absorption or emission?